# How to drop and add a new list of columns to a .csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am saving to a .csv file a preprocessed file with pandas `to_csv()` function as follows:

```
return df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')
```

The output of the `.csv` file looks like this:

```
|id|content|content2
0|id1|some content|some content
1|id1|some content|some content
....
n|idn|more content|even more content
```

As you can see from the above pandas objetct, the columns are not well formed:

```
|id|content|content2
```

How can I remove the above columns and replace them for this new columns setting:

```
id|content|content2
```

In other words:

```
id|content|content2
id1|some content|some content
id1|some content|some content
....
idn|more content|even more content
```

I all ready tried with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(output_file, sep='|', index_col=1)[['id','content', 'content2']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just wish to remove the index from the output

```
df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!. Is there anyway to remove the index before using `to_csv` function, in order to add a new header to the final .csv file?

Comment: `DataFrame`s always have an index, so no getting out of having one, you could either replace it with another column (e.g. `df.index == df['some_column']`) or you could just get the values of the `DataFrame` with `df.values`, which returns a Numpy array of the values of the `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks!, could you provide an example?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':['d','e','f']})`, then to reindex `df.index = df['c']`, then to drop the column now used as the index `df.drop('c',axis=1,inplace=True)`.

Comment: I tried your approach: `df.index = df['']``df.drop('',axis=1,inplace=True`), Then: `return df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')`. However, I got this exception:`File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4027)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3891)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12359)
KeyError: '' `

Comment: It looks like you are referencing a column with the name `''`, which doesn't exist in your dataframe

Comment: If you can see the columns of my dataframe (e.g. `|id|content|content2`). It actually exist, and it is separated by a pipe. Any idea of how to trim the whole dataframe in order to have something like this: `id|content|content2`

Comment: the current index does not have a name, which is why you see that in the output header -- I think your easiest solution is using the code I posted in the original answer